# Is there a scientific opinion about the connection between Asperger Syndrome and AD(H)D?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience

I have Aspergers and ADD. When I read autobiographies (most of all by female aspergers) I often think that they have actually *at least* a mild form of ADD or ADHD, too.

A German doctor (Dr. Helga Simchen) wrote she thinks that Asperger Syndrome should rather be on the AD(H)S spectrum than on the autism spectrum.
My personal opinion is: no. They're nevertheless different things.

But what is the current scientific standpoint about AS and AD(H)S?

Comment: Hi Aspergirl, welcome at CogSci and what an interesting first question. If you don't mind I did slightly rephrase the question as to focus less on opinions; opinion-based questions are tended to be closed here namely.

Answer (score 2):

There is a significant overlap between symptoms of classic Autism, Asperger syndrome, AD(H)D and OCD.

The following graph gives a good overview of how they are correlated at the behavioral and sensory level:

[image]
([source](http://theemergencesite.com/Tech/TechIssues-Autism-OCD-Aspergers-ADD.htm))

---

#### Further reading

- [Common brain changes found in children with autism, ADHD and OCD](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2016/07/160727110911.htm)
- [The Co-Occurrence of Autism and Attention Deficit Hyperactivity Disorder in Children – What Do We Know?](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4010758/)
- [Autistic traits in some children with ADHD](http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/265251.php)
- [A Third Of Autism Cases Also Have ADHD Symptoms](http://www.medicalnewstoday.com/articles/261526.php)
- [Autism and ADHD: Overlapping and discriminating symptoms](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1750946711001036)
- [Autism and ADHD Share Genetic Similarities](http://www.livescience.com/15503-autism-adhd-share-genetic-similarities.html)
- [Timing of the Diagnosis of Attention-Deficit/Hyperactivity Disorder and Autism Spectrum Disorder](http://pediatrics.aappublications.org/content/early/2015/09/08/peds.2015-1502)

Comment: Hi John, that's a really nice answer. However, it's a shame there are no direct scientific references on the website, which we could refer to.  Adding some to your post would greatly increase the quality of your post  and will definitely be appreciated by other CogSci members.

Comment: @RobinKramer : I added a couple of sources that address the differences and overlap between Autism & ADHD.